# Scala + Play -> Type mismatch; found : anorm.RowParser Required: anorm.ResultSetParser[Option[models.User]]

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework

SOLUTION:  I could not figure our how to return the non-exists for of Option[User] so in the case of not user found I create a dummy user object and reason on it from the controller (feels awful but working...):
from Application.scala

```
val loginForm = Form(
tuple(
  "email" -> text,
  "password" -> text
) verifying ("Invalid email or password", result => result match {
  case (email, password)  => (User.authenticate(email, password).map{_.id}.getOrElse(0) != 0)
})
```

)

AS OPPOSED TO:

```
val loginForm = Form(
  tuple(
  "email" -> text,
  "password" -> text
) verifying ("Invalid email or password", result => result match {
  case (email, password) => User.authenticate(email, password).isDefined
})
```

)

++++++++++++++++++ ORIGINAL 2 ++++++++++++++++++
Thanks for the advice! I have made some change and seem to be getting closer however I can't figure out how to return an undefinded Option[user]. I have also tried case _ => null, See below:

From User.scala

```
case class User(id: Int, email: String, name: String, password: String)

object User {

  // -- Parsers

  /**
   * Parse a User from a ResultSet
   */
  val userParser = {
            get[Option[Int]]("uid")~        
            get[Option[String]]("email")~
            get[Option[String]]("fname")~
            get[Option[String]]("pbkval") map {
            case (uid~email~name~pbkval) => validate(uid,email, name, pbkval)
            }
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve a User from email.
   */
  def findByEmail(email: String): Option[User] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("select * from get_pbkval({email})").on(
                'email -> email         
            ).as(userParser.singleOpt)
    }
  }


  /**
   * Authenticated user session start.
   */
  def authenticate(email: String, password: String): Option[User] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL(
            """
                        select * from get_pbkval({email})
            """
            ).on(
                'email -> email
            ).as(userParser.singleOpt)

        }
    }

  /**
   * Validate entry and create user object.
   */
    def validate(uid: Option[Int], email: Option[String], fname: Option[String], pbkval: Option[String]): User = {
                val uidInt : Int = uid.getOrElse(0)
                val emailString: String = email.getOrElse(null)
                val fnameString: String = fname.getOrElse(null)
                val pbkvalString: String = pbkval.getOrElse(null)
                User(uidInt, emailString, fnameString, pbkvalString)
    }
```

I guess it is clear that I am not really getting something fundamental here.. I have read through http://www.playframework.org/modules/scala-0.9.1/anorm and searched around for hours.. any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify which rows to map. After your row mapper, put a * to signify which rows to map. While you're at it, I find it easier to define my row mapper in a separate val. Something like this.

```scala
 val user = { 
   get[Option[Int]]("uid")~        
   get[Option[String]]("email")~
   get[Option[String]]("fname")~
   get[Option[String]]("pbkval") map {
    case uid~email~name~password => validate(uid,email, name, password)
  }
}

def authenticate(email: String, password: String): Option[User] = {
DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL(
    """
        select * from get_pbkval({email})
    """
    ).on(
        'email -> email
    ).as(user *)
  }
 } 

    def validate(uid: Option[Int], email: Option[String], fname: Option[String], pbkval: Option[String]): Option[User] = {
    if (uid != None) {
            val uidInt : Int = uid.getOrElse(0)
            val emailString: String = email.getOrElse(null)
            val fnameString: String = fname.getOrElse(null)
            val pbkvalString: String = pbkval.getOrElse(null)
            User(uidInt, emailString, fnameString, pbkvalString)
    } else { return null}
}
```

Note the "as" method now has two arguments, your row mapper (which is now defined as a val "user", and a "*" signifying that you want to map all of the rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben, I have made the changes you suggest and feeling much closer - I am now getting this error: type mismatch; found : anorm.ResultSetParser[List[Option[models.User]]] required: anorm.ResultSetParser[Option[models.User]]

Comment: ```*``` signifies you're returning a collection of users, so you may want to modify the return type. Otherwise you'd use ```user.singleOpt```, but then your ```WHERE``` clause would probably be on a unique identifier of some sort. (I would edit the answer, but can't guarantee it will compile without spinning up a project, which I don't have time for ;-)